# Python. File encoding when read file by url

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I need to get file by URL and return string with the most words count from this file. Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def wordiest_line(url):
    data = urlopen(url)

    if data:
        max_words = 0
        max_line = ""
        for line in data.readlines(): 
            #print(line)
            the_encoding = "utf-8"
            line = line.decode(the_encoding)
            line = line.rstrip()
            line_words = line.split()
            if len(line_words) > max_words:
                max_words = len(line_words)
                max_line = line

        #print("%s to RETURN\n" % max_line)
        return max_line

    else:
        return None
```

And these are some URLs given to test this function:

1. "http://math-info.hse.ru/f/2017-18/dj-prog/lines1.txt"
2. "http://lib.ru/FOUNDATION/3laws.txt_Ascii.txt"
3. "http://math-info.hse.ru/f/2017-18/dj-prog/lines2.txt"

For links 1 and 3 it works fine. 
But     `wordiest_line("http://lib.ru/FOUNDATION/3laws.txt_Ascii.txt")`
doesn't work properly because of file encoding, there is some text in cyrillic.

I tried to define what string encoding is and decode it. Here is code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import chardet    

def wordiest_line(url):
    data = urlopen(url)

    if data:
        max_words = 0
        max_line = ""
        for line in data.readlines(): 
            #print(line)
            the_encoding = chardet.detect(line)['encoding']
            line = line.decode(the_encoding)
            #print(the_encoding, line)
            line = line.rstrip()
            line_words = line.split()
            if len(line_words) > max_words:
                max_words = len(line_words)
                max_line = line

        #print("%s to RETURN\n" % max_line)
        return max_line

    else:
        return None
```

And now `wordiest_line("http://lib.ru/FOUNDATION/3laws.txt_Ascii.txt")` fails with error: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 8: character maps to undefined

Other URLs still works fine. Have you any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The `chardet` library can be a life-saver if you have to guess or fix encoding of messy input.
However, in your case this information is given – at least for the *lib.ru* example.
As expected from any well-behaving server, the charset of a plain-text response is specified in the "Content-Type" header:

```
import codecs
from urllib.request import urlopen

def wordiest_line(url):
    resp = urlopen(url)
    charset = resp.headers.get_content_charset()
    textreader = codecs.getreader(charset)(resp)
    for line in textreader:
        line = line.rstrip()
        # continue with tokenising and counting...
```

Note: I assume that you are using Python 3; the above code won't work in Python 2.
Also, I suggest you decode the content before iterating over the lines of the file, assuming you won't be given broken input like badly messed-up files with differently encoded lines.

Second note: the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library will probably allow you to write less boiler-plate code for this task.

Third note: For counting words, `line.split()` is rather simplistic. For example, "argue," and "argue" will be considered different words, and you might even want to define "arguing" and "argued" as belonging to the same word. In that case, you'll have to use an NLP library, such as NLTK or SpaCy.

Answer (score 0):

Python allows you to do fault tolerant decoding with `decode(encoding, 'replace') which replace any offending character with the official U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

Here if unsure of the encoding (of if the solution proposed by @lenz was not convenient), you should use:

```
        line = line.decode(the_encoding, 'replace')
```

Even with an utf8 encoding, it identifies the correct line but of course cannot correctly decode it

Alternatively you can use the fact that the Latin1 encoding just convert any byte into the unicode character of same code value. Here you could do:

```
        try:
            line = line.decode(the_encoding)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            line = line.decode('Latin1')
```

Not only this correctly idendifies the correct line, but with:

```
line = wordiest_line("http://lib.ru/FOUNDATION/3laws.txt_Ascii.txt")
orig = line.encode('Latin)
```

you get the original line in raw bytes and can examine it to now correctly decode it.

BTW, the correct encoding for the file is KOI8-R